# How to delete tables with specific names in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Guru's please help me with this.

I have a master table called `ABC`, each month we create new table and suffix with month and year `ABC_012010`, `ABC_022010`.

I have to keep these tables for 7 years, and delete any table which are more than 7 years.

So the job would delete `ABC_012010` in Feb 2017, `ABC_022010` would be deleted in March 2017 and so on

The job runs every month to check and delete any table, which fits the criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TRY THIS**: You need `dynamic query, loop and temporary tables` to perform this operation and your table format must be in the same format as you have mentioned in your example. You can perform `INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, TRUNCATE` in this way in multiple tables:

```
    --Selecting table name in date format with `LEFT` `RIGHT` function
SELECT name, 
    CAST(CONCAT(LEFT(RIGHT(name, 6), 2), '-01-', RIGHT(RIGHT(name, 6), 4)) AS DATE) AS tableDate, 
    CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS currentDate
INTO #tmp_date 
FROM sys.objects 
WHERE TYPE = 'u' AND NAME LIKE 'ABC[_]%'

--Storing table names that are older than 7 years from current date
SELECT id = IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1), 
    NAME 
INTO #object_name FROM #tmp_date 
WHERE (DATEDIFF(MM,tableDate, currentDate)-1) > = 84 

DECLARE @i INT = 1, @j INT, @sql VARCHAR(500), @object_name VARCHAR(100)

SELECT @j = MAX(id) FROM #object_name

WHILE @i < = @j 
BEGIN
    SELECT @object_name = NAME FROM #object_name WHERE id = @i
    SET @sql = 'DELETE FROM ' + @object_name --can use `DROP` to drop the table
    EXEC (@sql)

    SET @i = @i+1

END
```

Comment: I think I never thanked for this, my apologies. I am now getting error "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string." nothing has changed so not sure why it's not working. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB.DBO.#TEMP_DEL', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TEMP_DEL
DECLARE @CYMO VARCHAR(8) = (SELECT '01' + RIGHT(REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(YY, -7, GETDATE()), 103), '/', ''), 6))
SELECT [NAME] TABLE_NAME INTO #TEMP_DEL FROM DBNAME.SYS.TABLES
WHERE [NAME] LIKE 'ABC%' AND '01'+RIGHT(NAME,6) < @CYMO
WHILE ((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM #TEMP_DEL) > 0)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TAB VARCHAR(100) = (SELECT TOP 1 TABLE_NAME FROM #TEMP_DEL)
    DECLARE @CMD NVARCHAR(200) = 'DROP TABLE '+@TAB
    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @CMD
    DELETE #TEMP_DEL WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TAB
END
```

Replace *DBNAME* with your database name.

HTH!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `dynamic query, while and if conditionals` to construct a stored procedure or scheduled job (as you like) to solve this issue. Try this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.delete_abc @Date date, @years_diff int
AS 
    --- Declare variables to use
    DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(30)
    DECLARE @table varchar(20)
    DECLARE @month int
    DECLARE @year int

    --- Temporary table with 'ABC_'s table names
    SELECT TABLE_NAME
    INTO #Temp
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'ABC_%'
    AND TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' -- If you want only tables

    ---- While there are tables to compare
    WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #Temp)
    BEGIN
        --- Extract Month and Year of the first row in 'ABC_'s table
        SET @month = (SELECT TOP 1 SUBSTRING(TABLE_NAME,5,2) FROM #Temp)
        SET @year = (SELECT TOP 1 SUBSTRING(TABLE_NAME,7,4) FROM #Temp)

        --- Compare if date difference of the table is more than @years_diff years from @Date
        IF DATEDIFF(YEAR, CAST(CAST(@year AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(@month AS VARCHAR) + '-01' AS DATE), DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @Date), 0)) > @years_diff 
            BEGIN
            --- Construct and execute delete query
            SET @table = (SELECT TOP 1 TABLE_NAME FROM #Temp)
            SET @sqlCommand = 'DROP TABLE ' + @table  --- or 'DELETE FROM ' if you only want to delete all rows from table
            EXEC(@sqlCommand)
            END

     --- Delete first row of 'ABC_'s tables in temporary
     DELETE TOP (1) FROM #Temp;

     END

     --- Drop temporary table
     DROP TABLE #Temp
GO;
```

Once it's created, you can use this stored procedure like this or with the parameters you like:

```
DECLARE @Now date
SET @Now = GETDATE()
EXEC dbo.delete_abc @years_diff = 7, @Date = @Now
```

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn't it be easy enough to make a delete query?

```
Delete From [Your_Table] Where [Date_Column] = 'ABC_012010'
```